# Prevent closing of JQuery Popup window

Tags: jquery, popup

I have the following JQuery popup window in my page.

```
$('#SubSkill').dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          draggable: false,
          resizable: false,
          bgiframe: false,
          modal: true,
          width: dWidth,
          height: dHeight,
          title: "Enter Job Sub Skill Information",
          open: function (type, data) {
              $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
          }
      });
```

When I clisk the `Escape` key, it closes. How do I prevent the closing of the popup when this key is pressed?

Comment: use [keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closeOnEscape: false` option:

```
$('#SubSkill').dialog({
    closeOnEscape: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    bgiframe: false,
    modal: true,
    width: dWidth,
    height: dHeight,
    title: "Enter Job Sub Skill Information",
    open: function (type, data) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
    }
});
```

**[References](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-closeOnEscape)**

Answer (score 0):

You must use the closeOnEscape property, and set it to false,

Here is your new script:

```
$('#SubSkill').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      draggable: false,
      resizable: false,
      bgiframe: false,
      modal: true,
      width: dWidth,
      height: dHeight,
      title: "Enter Job Sub Skill Information",
      open: function (type, data) {
          $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
      },
      closeOnEscape: false 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your function.

```
closeOnEscape: false
```